# Is there any way to read Xlsx file in pyspark?Also want to read strings of column from each columnName

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

pd is a panda module is one way of reading excel but its not available in my cluster. I want to read excel without pd module. Code1 and Code2 are two implementations i want in pyspark.

## Code 1: Reading Excel

```
pdf = pd.read_excel(Name.xlsx)
sparkDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pdf)
df = sparkDF.rdd.map(list)
type(df)
```

Want to implement without pandas module

## Code 2: gets list of strings from column colname in dataframe df

```
stringsList = []
columnList = list(df[colname])
for i in range(len(columnList)):
    if type(columnList[i]) != float:
        text = columnList[i]
        stringsList.append(text.lower())    
    else:
        stringsList.append(u'')
return stringsList
```

I want to implement this in pyspark.

Comment: Why don't you convert the Excel files before uploading them to the cluster? If you are allowed to install libraries there's https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel

Comment: It does not depend on me its requirement.They want data from excel only.Thanks for response @Emre

Answer (score 1):

Is pandas itself available on the cluster?
If so, you may try to go with the in-built [`read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).

You may also try the [HadoopOffice](https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice/wiki) library, it contains a [Spark DataSource](https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/spark-hadoopoffice-ds/), also available as [Spark Package](https://spark-packages.org/package/ZuInnoTe/spark-hadoopoffice-ds), you can easily test it out without any installation:

`$SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark --packages com.github.zuinnote:spark-hadoopoffice-ds_2.11:1.0.4`

Some people also [recommend the `Spark Excel` dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44197455/3613057).

Comment: Pandas not available in cluster.Will try with hadoopOffice but I am not not sure whether I can use it or not.

Comment: The [Spark Excel](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel) I mentioned doesn't require installation too, e.g.: `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.9.12`

Comment: Is there any way without any installation I can do this.

Comment: Please take a look at my previous comment, right above yours :]

Answer (score 1):

You need the jar **crealytics**. Use the link - [jar](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.crealytics/spark-excel_2.11/0.8.2/source-code) to download the jar

Try this, it would help!

```py
def get_df_from_excel(sqlContext, file_name):
    """    
    This method is intended to create a dataframe form excel file
    :param sqlContext: sqlContext
    :param file_name:  - Address of file 
    :return: dataframe
    """
    return sqlContext.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
        .option("useHeader", "true") \
        .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true") \
        .option("inferSchema", "true") \
        .option("addColorColumns", "False") \
        .option("maxRowsInMey", 2000) \
        .option("sheetName", "Import") \
        .load(file_name)
```